# Neo4j Cypher Return custom JSON structure

Tags: json, neo4j, graphql, cypher, cytoscape.js

I am trying to convert the graph structure to json.

I have the following structure

```
CREATE (ui)-[:CONTAINS]->(graphStyle:SchemaType {id: randomUUID(), name:'graphStyle', type:'array', shape:'star'})
CREATE (graphStyle)-[:CONTAINS]->(graphStyleNode:Field {id: randomUUID(), name:'node', type:'object', shape:'star'})
CREATE (graphStyleNode)-[:CONTAINS]->(graphStyleNodeSelector:Field {id: randomUUID(), name:'selector', type:'string', value: "node", shape:'star'})
CREATE (graphStyleNode)-[:CONTAINS]->(graphStyleNodeStyle:Field {id: randomUUID(), name:'style', type:'object', value: "node", shape:'star'})
CREATE (graphStyleNodeStyle)-[:CONTAINS]->(graphStyleNodeStyleFontFamily:Field {id: randomUUID(), name:"'font-family'", type:'string', value: "-apple-system, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif", shape:'star'})
CREATE (graphStyleNodeStyle)-[:CONTAINS]->(graphStyleNodeStyleFontSize:Field {id: randomUUID(), name:"'font-size'", type:'string', value: "8px", shape:'star'})
CREATE (graphStyleNodeStyle)-[:CONTAINS]->(graphStyleNodeStyleWidth:Field {id: randomUUID(), name:'width', type:'function', value: '(ele:any) => {if (ele.data().shape !== "round-rectangle") return 60; else return 100}', shape:'star'})
CREATE (graphStyleNodeStyle)-[:CONTAINS]->(graphStyleNodeStyleHeight:Field {id: randomUUID(), name:'height', type:'function', value: '(ele:any) => {if (ele.data().shape !== "round-rectangle") return 60; else return 40}', shape:'star'})
CREATE (graphStyleNodeStyle)-[:CONTAINS]->(graphStyleNodeStyleBackgroundColor:Field {id: randomUUID(), name:"'background-color'", type:'string', value: "#5E6366", shape:'star'})
CREATE (graphStyleNodeStyle)-[:CONTAINS]->(graphStyleNodeStyleLabel:Field {id: randomUUID(), name:'label', type:'string', value: "", shape:'star'})
CREATE (graphStyleNodeStyle)-[:CONTAINS]->(graphStyleNodeStyleTextHAlign:Field {id: randomUUID(), name:"'text-halign'", type:'string', value: "center", shape:'star'})
CREATE (graphStyleNodeStyle)-[:CONTAINS]->(graphStyleNodeStyleTextVAlign:Field {id: randomUUID(), name:"'text-valign'", type:'string', value: "center", shape:'star'})
CREATE (graphStyleNodeStyle)-[:CONTAINS]->(graphStyleNodeStyleTextMarginY:Field {id: randomUUID(), name:"'text-margin-y'", type:'string', value: "5px", shape:'star'})
CREATE (graphStyleNodeStyle)-[:CONTAINS]->(graphStyleNodeStyleTextWrap:Field {id: randomUUID(), name:"'text-wrap'", type:'string', value: "ellipsis", shape:'star'})
CREATE (graphStyleNodeStyle)-[:CONTAINS]->(graphStyleNodeStyleTextMaxWidth:Field {id: randomUUID(), name:"'text-max-width'", type:'string', value: "50px", shape:'star'})
CREATE (graphStyleNodeStyle)-[:CONTAINS]->(graphStyleNodeStyleColor:Field {id: randomUUID(), name:'color', type:'string', value: "#FFFFFF", shape:'star'})
CREATE (graphStyleNodeStyle)-[:CONTAINS]->(graphStyleNodeStyleOverlayOpacity:Field {id: randomUUID(), name:"'overlay-opacity'", type:'number', value: 0, shape:'star'})
CREATE (graphStyleNodeStyle)-[:CONTAINS]->(graphStyleNodeStyleTextBackgroundOpacity:Field {id: randomUUID(), name:"'text-background-opacity'", type:'number', value: 1, shape:'star'})
CREATE (graphStyleNodeStyle)-[:CONTAINS]->(graphStyleNodeStyleBackgroundPositionY:Field {id: randomUUID(), name:"'background-position-y'", type:'string', value: "30%", shape:'star'})
CREATE (graphStyleNodeStyle)-[:CONTAINS]->(graphStyleNodeStyleBorderWidth:Field {id: randomUUID(), name:"'border-width'", type:'string', value: "2px", shape:'star'})
CREATE (graphStyleNodeStyle)-[:CONTAINS]->(graphStyleNodeStyleShape:Field {id: randomUUID(), name:"'shape'", type:'string', value: "data(shape)", shape:'star'})
CREATE (graphStyleNodeStyle)-[:CONTAINS]->(graphStyleNodeStyleShape:Field {id: randomUUID(), name:"'shape'", type:'string', value: "data(shape)", shape:'star'})
```

And I would like to return:

```
{
  style: [{
    selector: "node",
    style: {
      "font-family":
        "-apple-system, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif",
      "font-size": "8px",
      width: (ele:any) => {if (ele.data().shape !== "round-rectangle") return 60; else return 100},
      height: (ele:any) => {if (ele.data().shape !== "round-rectangle") return 60; else return 40},
      "background-color": "#5E6366",
      label: "",
      "text-halign": "center",
      "text-valign": "center",
      "text-margin-y": "5px",
      "text-wrap": "ellipsis",
      "text-max-width": "50px",
      color: "#ffffff",
      "overlay-opacity": 0,
      "text-background-opacity": 1,
      "background-position-y": "30%",
      "border-width": "2px",
      "shape": "data(shape)"
    }]
},
```

The problem becomes when using apoc.convert.toJson that I cannot set the json key to be the node name and value to be the node value. The json is a cytoscape js style so that's why it has suck a weird structure.

Comment: What have you tried?  How does graphql plus cryptoscape.js come into this?

Comment: You've transformed the structure with cryptoscape.js. APOC is not designed to handle that.